# Unknown error while using Microsoft Graph Communication API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

We are trying to use the `Microsoft Graph Communication APIs` in order to make the peer-to-peer calls based on the [Create Call using Communication API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=javascript)

Based on the request payload when we try to fire the same query using `Graph Explorer` and the `node.js` sample we do get the same error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "9342e7a0-2d26-4e59-b7f4-c89a4a52e2d5",
            "date": "2020-06-11T06:47:03"
        }
    }
}
```

So far we have created the App under the `App Registration` over `Microsoft Azure` and assigned the required permissions for `Graph Api Calling`

[image]

Request payload for create call that we are using is based on the [Create Call Sample Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) provided by Microsoft itself.

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.call",
    "callbackUri": "http://localhost:31544/",
    "targets": [{
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.invitationParticipantInfo",
      "countryCode": "91",
      "identity": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identitySet",
        "user": {
          "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identity",
          "displayName": "Maggie",
          "tenantId": "150d7f46-ce04-4895-b4bd-1112221122",
          "id": "a27c62fb-a420-4fa5-87eb-2221112121"
        }
      }
    }],
    "requestedModalities": ["audio"],
    "mediaConfig": {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.serviceHostedMediaConfig"
    }
  }
```

Not sure what is wrong with the payload or URL as we do get `404 unknown error` every time we execute the request.

[image]

**Edit**

1. I have granted all the required permissions now

[image]

2. Then I tried to call calling following URL for admin consent

   https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent

[image]

3. after that I tried to call following URL in POSTMAN to get the token

   https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/v2.0/token
4. use the same token to make a call but getting the same error

   https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/communications/calls

**Edit**

5. Now after calling the following URL I do get error in  POSTMAN

   https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/calls

***Error***

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "{\"errorCode\":\"7503\",\"message\":\"Application is not registered in our store.\",\"instanceAnnotations\":[]}",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-06-12T16:11:47",
      "request-id": "d25c41fd-afc4-462b-a811-46e7286a0df6"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=javascript#permissions), the *Delegated permission* is not supported, it just supports *Application permission*, so you need to use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the token and call the API(e.g. use the postman) instead of using the Microsoft Graph Explorer, in the Microsoft Graph Explorer, the *Application permission* will not take effect.

[image]

Also, I notice you don't click the `Grant admin consent for xxx` button in the `API permission` page of your AD App, it is required when you grant the permission for your app, the status should be like below.

[image]

Comment: @Hunt The request url should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/calls`, don't use `/me`.Also, decode the token in https://jwt.io/, see if the permissions are included in the `roles`, like https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoCTf.png

Comment: i have decoded the token and I can see the permission there but while calling the service I got a new error , see the edit (Step 5) please

Comment: @Hunt You need to register the calling bot first, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot

Comment: @Hunt If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thanks.

Comment: Today I am going to create not app and let you know as I wasn't knowing why we need to create bot app to communicate User A of teams to user B ? Do you have any idea

Comment: @Hunt Sry, I have no idea, just from this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiGj3.png, I think it's your job.;-)